# Can't able to reach identity.apple.com/pushcert portal for creating a Apple Push certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to configure a MDM for all my mobile phones. But for iPhone, I need to create a Apple Push certification to do that, but can't able to reach the portal  identity.apple.com/pushcert and getting Forbidden error.  Do anyone guide me what went wrong with this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like probably your trying to access using http instead of https.

https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/ should work. Else please re-check if its not the routing issue between your service provider & Apple.

Regards,
_Ayush

Comment: Now I can able to reach, but its not the problem of http/https.I faced earlier.  I was just using the direct link provided by apple instead of typing it manually. So, https/http should not be a problem here. Anyway, I can reach now.

Comment: Sure. Actually looks like this issue is random. For me also, same issue happened even for both unsecured as well as secured link. It works randomly for me now.

Answer (score 0):

if you have previous files related to certificates on your computer delete them these include csr and pem files.  go back to portal link and you will find it will now navigate to the actual link.